# Find a basis for the null space of a linear transformation given by a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$L_A$: $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined by $x \mapsto Ax$ where

$$
    A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & -9\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -3\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & -5\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

i applied an approach i found here after searching the web because lecture and text material didn't cover this topic:

https://yutsumura.com/how-to-find-a-basis-for-the-nullspace-row-space-and-range-of-a-matrix/

i'm not 100% sure the above approach was the correct one.

using elementary row operations i found:

$$ N(L_A) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -2 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    2 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

was this the correct approach? thanks for any insights.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you would be given a homework question on a topic that wasn't covered by the lecture and materials.  Which textbook are you using?

Comment: linear algebra 4th ed by freidberg, lawrence and spence. these topics are covered in a general way but i am finding it increasingly difficult to connect text/lecture material to homework questions. like there's no example problem that i could use as a model to approach this question.

Comment: Lawrence is Spence's first name; so I suspect you mean Friedberg Insel and Spence.  I haven't looked at that textbook in a while but your criticism makes sense, especially if your instructor is giving you the usual kinds of linear algebra homework assignments rather than questions from the book.  Is this question taken from the book?

Comment: yes, that book. sorry about that error. it's a very popular text. and no, this question isn't from the book.

Comment: Regarding this discussion: I would recommend that you learn how to row-reduce a matrix and learn how to extract bases for the nullspace and range/column-space using the row-reduced matrix. Other than that, everything you need should be there in the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer so far is correct.  In particular, row reducing your matrix gives us
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & -9\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -3\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & -5\\
    \end{pmatrix} \leadsto
\pmatrix{
1&0&2&0&-2\\
0&1&-1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&-2
}.
$$
Columns 1,2,4 are "pivot-columns", and the remaining columns are "free-columns" (following the terminology of Strang's *Linear Algebra*.  I think that Lay's text uses similar terminology.)

By looking at the free columns of the row-reduced matrix, we can find a basis for the nullspace.  The way that you did so is great, and your answer is correct.

Comment: so i'm finished?

Comment: Yes. The two column-vectors that you have found are a basis for the nullspace, so you're done.  Stating that $N(L_A)$ is equal to those two vectors is technically wrong, so don't do that.  Instead, say that the set of these two vectors is a basis of $N(L_A)$.

Comment: thank you for your help! i was unsure if i was on the right track because i thought i may have calculated $N(A)$ instead of $N(L_A)$. but i guess something implied but not stated here is that A is a matrix representation of $L_A$?

Comment: Saying that "A is a matrix representation of $L_A$" means exactly the same thing as "$L:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is defined by $x \mapsto Ax$", so it is actually stated explicitly and not just implied.  Also, note that what you have found is a **basis for $N(L_A)$**, not $N(L_A)$.  Confusing these two statements is bound to lose you points

Comment: Also, I forget FIS's terminology, but typically a "nullspace" is something belonging to a matrix, whereas a "kernel" is the corresponding structure for a linear transformation; your text and teacher's usage may vary.